# Invalid User Name or Password after moving from sub-domain to main domain

Tags: admin, database, password

After moving from sub-domain to main domain,

I can not able to login to admin panel. getting following message :

Invalid User Name or Password.

I set proper password which is in Admin_user[with md5] in database.

please help me to find solution.

Comment: check domain . setting

Comment: Hi,

I just created the new database. that's worked.

Thanks a lot for helping me again and again.

Comment: please create an answer to your own question explaining how you solved your problem and accept it.

Comment: hi Julien, Thanks a lot for reply. I just created the entire datbase again & changed the password in admin_user [using md5]. That's what i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it may be issue with cookies domain
.check your cookie domain
.c
Cookie domain was set at old domain

Answer (score 1):

Do you really get the notification of wrong user/pass
often after moving the site i get similar issues, but then without any notification "assuming" that its the user pass but in reality its due to sessions not able to write.

and check your cookie domain or cookie settings

Comment: Hi Kay, Thanks a lot for reply. YEs I got invalid user and pass. Instead of trying to search some solutions,  I just created another database. problem solved.

Comment: Haha great news. those darn databases!